# Under what conditions will winsock blocking send() return 0?

Tags: sockets, winsock, send, blocking

MSDN says the following:
"Calling send with a len parameter of zero is permissible and will be treated by implementations as successful. In such cases, send will return zero as a valid value. For message-oriented sockets, a zero-length transport datagram is sent."

My question is, if the len parameter is NOT zero, will the blocking send() return 0 (assuming no timeout is set)?

I also searched the Internet, and found the following:

http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html

"Under Winsock, the SIGPIPE/EPIPE functionality does not exist at all: send() will either return 0 for a normal disconnect or -1 for an abnormal disconnect".

However, no matter how I tried, I couldn't simulate the "normal disconnect", and therefore I could NOT have send() return 0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A "normal" disconnect is when the receiving party calls `closesocket()` on its end of the connection to send a `FIN` packet to the sending party.  When `send()` detects the `FIN`, it knows the connection has been disconnected gracefully and should return 0 to notify your code.

Comment: send() will still succeed even if a FIN has been received. FIN can be caused by closesocket, shutdown(SD_SEND), shutdown(SD_BOTH).
For the shutdown(SD_SEND) case, subsequent send()s will always succeed, because the other party (who called shutdown(SD_SEND)) is supposed to receive any further data. However, a call to recv() will return 0.

For closesocket and shutdown(SD_BOTH) (and also shutdown(SD_RECEIVE)), the first send() will still succeed; however, a RST will be returned. The next time when send() or recv()  is called, SOCKET_ERROR(-1) will be returned.

Comment: To summarize, no matter what causes the FIN, send() will either succeed (the first time call after the FIN was received), or will return -1 due to RST (the second time and future calls).
That is, the blocking send() will never return 0? right? (assuming no timeout is set)